# How does jQuery Autocomplete dynamically filter responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, autocomplete

I am currently using http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/#jquery-autocomplete to autocomplete input.

My question is: **how is the demo at the above link automatically filtering results?**

If I use a local datastore, it filters the results for me.

```
<script>
var suggestions = [ "Afghan", 
                    "African", 
                    "Senegalese", 
                    "American", 
                    "Arabian", 
                    "Arab Pizza", 
                    "Argentine", 
                    "Armenian", 
                    "Asian Fusion", 
                    "Asturian", 
                    "Australian", 
                    "Austrian" 
                  ]
$('#categories').autocomplete({
    // serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/categories',
    lookup: suggestions,
    delimiter: ',',
    maxHeight: 200,
    minChars: 2
});
</script>
```

However, if I instead replace "lookup:" with an external datastore (serviceUrl), the results are no longer filtered.

Here's my code for the external-calls version:

```
class AjaxHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, response):
        self.initialize(request, response)
        self.categories = []
        with open("static/categories.data") as categories_file:
            for entry in categories_file:
                self.categories.append(str(entry))
                print entry


    def get(self):
        suggestions = {"suggestions": self.categories}
        self.response.write(json.dumps(suggestions))
        self.response.headers.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset-UTF-8")
```

With this version, it's still doing an edit-distance with all of the entries, but filtering is no longer working.

Here is their API: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete
There's a bunch of options there, and if anyone can give me some pointers to which one might help, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

That demo isn't using an external data source.

But I'm not sure what you're asking: the whole point of using an external data source is that it's the source that does the filtering - it only returns values that match the token that is sent with the Ajax get. Otherwise you might as well include all the data in the original request.

Comment: Oh, I was using the external source because it contains a lot of data entries. I wanted to read in the entries rather than putting all of the entries in a Javascript array. Is that perhaps not the way it's supposed to be used?

Answer (score -1):

When you trying to request to other server with your javascript usually it will be blocked by Web Browser because of Security Concern. (You can google by keyword `Cross domain javascript request`)

If you using java, you can create some java code - Controller or Servlet (not javascript) that request to other Server and pass it to your html (Just like a bridge). Or you can do same thing if you using with PHP or Python.